# Generate a QR code with contact details & URL.Perform both operation to Open Url in web browser & add contact details by using any QR code app

Tags: qr-code

I want to generate a QR code that contains URL & Contact detail both. But real problem is that i want to perform both operation to add contact details in our contact list & open a URL link in web browser with any of QR code reader app. Is it possible with any other way.
Please suggest any solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can generate a Contact QR Code (for example here: http://qrdroid.com/generate > Contact). Add contact information, including Website. When you scan that code with QR Droid (http://q.qr.ai) or most other scanners, you'll have an option to either add the full contact or just open entered URL. But none (or at most only one) action will be performed automatically. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

you can think of qr codes like text files. only the programm which parses the file decides what to do. 
maybe some scanners will recognise the URL and VCard seperate but you can't really count on it.